# Angular 7 HttpClient ConcatMap error handling

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have some code that performs uploads of a large file in smaller chunks. Here is what I have:

```
upload(project: Project): Observable<any> {

    var chunks = this.chunkFiles(project);

    var totalPercent = project.file
        .map(file => Math.ceil(file.size / this.chunkSize))
        .reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr) * 100;

    var finishedPercent = 0;
    var currentPercent = 0;

    return from(chunks)
        .pipe(
            concatMap(request =>
            {
                return this.http.request(request)
                    .pipe(
                        retryWhen(error =>
                        {
                            return interval(1000)
                                .pipe(
                                    flatMap(count =>
                                    {
                                        if (count == 2)
                                        {
                                            return throwError(error);
                                        }
                                        return of(count);
                                    })
                                );
                        }));
            }),
            map(event =>
            {
                if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
                {
                    var progress = event as HttpProgressEvent;
                    currentPercent = Math.round(100 * progress.loaded / progress.total);
                    return {
                        type: event.type,
                        loaded: finishedPercent + currentPercent,
                        total: totalPercent
                    };
                }
                else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) 
                {
                    finishedPercent += 100;
                    if (finishedPercent == totalPercent)
                    {
                        return event;
                    }
                }
            }),
            filter(response => response !== undefined)
        );
}
```

The intention is that it starts uploading chunks of the file and once one of the chunk uploads fails, it should stop and the error should propagate up to the code that is calling my upload function. That particular code is as follows:

```
onStartUpload = this.actions$
    .ofType(forRoot.START_UPLOAD).pipe(
    switchMap((action: forRoot.StartUpload) =>
        this.uploadService
            .upload(action.project).pipe(
            map((event) => {
                if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                    const progress = event as HttpProgressEvent;
                    const percentDone = Math.round(100 * progress.loaded / progress.total);
                    return new forRoot.UploadProgress(percentDone);
                } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    return new forRoot.UploadSucceeded();
                } else {
                    console.log(event);
                }
            }),
            filter(a => a !== undefined),
            catchError(error => {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 400) {
                    const message = this.getMessage(error);
                    return of(new forRoot.UploadFailed(message || "Bad request"));
                } else {
                    return of(new forRoot.UploadFailed("Network error"));
                }
            })))
        );
```

The problem is that I only get a "Network error" message, whereas I'm expecting something with error status 400 (so I should be getting either the specific message or "Bad request".

I'm assuming I'm not properly handling the error within the retryWhen, but I've tried a few different ideas and none seem to work. What am I missing?

**Edit to show working code without retry:**

Here is code that has correct error message handling, however it has no retry:

```
return from(chunks)
    .pipe(
        concatMap(request =>
        {
            return this.http.request(request)
        }),
        map(event =>
        {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
            {
                var progress = event as HttpProgressEvent;
                currentPercent = Math.round(100 * progress.loaded / progress.total);
                return {
                    type: event.type,
                    loaded: finishedPercent + currentPercent,
                    total: totalPercent
                };
            }
            else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) 
            {
                finishedPercent += 100;
                if (finishedPercent == totalPercent)
                {
                    return event;
                }
            }
        }),
        filter(response => response !== undefined)
    );
```

I've been assuming there is something I can add to the http.request call to retry a specified number of times with a delay in between retries, and then if they all fail, throw an error just like http.request does. What seems to happen is that it proceeds past the concatMap code to the map code. I can add console.log(event) calls and see the error message returned from the server. I'm still pretty new at rxjs, so maybe I don't understand, but I was expecting once the error happened that it wouldn't execute the map code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```js
retryWhen(error => {     // << error is a stream
  return interval(1000)
    .pipe(
        flatMap(count => {
          if (count == 2){
              return throwError(error); // so here a stream is thrown
          }

          return of(count);
      })
    );
})
```

`error` argument is not a single error, but actually an Observable of all errors happening.

To fix this you should return observable derived from `error`, e.g.:

```js
retryWhen(errors$ =>
  errors$.pipe(
    delay(1000)
  )
)
```

**Updated example** of limited error handling

```js
retryWhen(errors =>
  errors.pipe(
    // switchMap to add limiting logic
    switchMap((error, index) =>
      index == 3                      // if it is a 4th error
      ? throwError(error)             //  -- we rethrow it upstream
      : of(error).pipe( delay(1000) ) //  -- delay a retry otherwise
    )
  )
)
```

Heres a [retryWhen example with exponential backoff](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/retryWhen/).

And an article [on error handling in rxjs](https://medium.com/@kddsky/error-handling-in-rxjs-bac0f96a7def) (with a note about `retryWhen` early completion).

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried a few different alternatives, but the concat(NEVER) keeps giving me issues. The error is:

ERROR in src/app/upload/state/upload.service.ts(151,33): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Observable<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, any>'.
  Type 'Observable<never>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<any>): Observable<any>'.

Comment: @Dan, Oh, this is probably due to `concat` being imported from `rxjs`, you should import it from `rxjs/operators`. Thats a common issue with that operator, I forgot to mention. Theres factory `concat` that creates Observable, and an operator, that processes Observables. We need the operator.

Comment: That fixed the error message and I was able to test, but it doesn't work. It seems like it's swallowing the error (the user doesn't get any error message). I'm going to edit the question to show working code that doesn't have retry.

Comment: @Dan, my bad, sorry. It was really swallowing errors. I've fixed that and updated the limited retries example. Add it to your code here `return this.http.request(request).pipe( ...retryWhen... )`